# Can't attach child process in release build (Android)

Tags: android, native, ptrace

I try to fork and then trace my child by calling ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, iChildPid, 0, 0) on Android:
 - and get success when working with a debug build
 - and get failure with a release build (Operation not permitted (1))

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay :(
This is an Android feature. If the application is not marked as debuggable (manifest: android:debuggable = false), PTRACE_ATTACH does not works in both directions (parent2child and child2parent). Only root can do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source of Android framework, you indeed can enable ptrace-able by yourself in app release build. (Just dont forget to call this function before your fork child process and ptrace parent)

frameworks/base/core/jni/com_android_internal_os_Zygote.cpp

```
static void EnableDebugger() {
  // To let a non-privileged gdbserver attach to this
  // process, we must set our dumpable flag.
  if (prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0) == -1) {
    ALOGE("prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) failed");
  }

  // A non-privileged native debugger should be able to attach to the debuggable app, even if Yama
  // is enabled (see kernel/Documentation/security/Yama.txt).
  if (prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY, 0, 0, 0) == -1) {
    // if Yama is off prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER) returns EINVAL - don't log in this
    // case since it's expected behaviour.
    if (errno != EINVAL) {
      ALOGE("prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY) failed");
    }
  }

  // Set the core dump size to zero unless wanted (see also coredump_setup in build/envsetup.sh).
  if (!GetBoolProperty("persist.zygote.core_dump", false)) {
    // Set the soft limit on core dump size to 0 without changing the hard limit.
    rlimit rl;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl) == -1) {
      ALOGE("getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed");
    } else {
      rl.rlim_cur = 0;
      if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl) == -1) {
        ALOGE("setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed");
      }
    }
  }
}
```